# Llamar a un Channel Consumer desde una vista django

Tags: python, django

Estoy tratando de llamar a una x funcion de un consumidor channels, desde una vista de django, pero la llamada nunca llega a la funcion y no entiendo por que.

views.py

```
def Llamar_a_Prueba():
        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)('hola', {"type": "probar","text": "probar"})
```

cosumers.py

```
class RevisionConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    
    async def connect(self):
        await self.channel_layer.group_add('hola',self.channel_name)
        await self.accept()
        await self.actualizar()

        
        

    async def disconnect(self,close_code):
        print("Se desconecto el socket")
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard('hola',self.channel_name)

    async def receive(self,text_data):
        data = json.loads(text_data)       
    

    async def actualizar(self):
        #print("entrooooooooooooooo")
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'Cantidad_de_Notificaciones': await self.actualizar_valor_cant_notificaciones()}))

    async def probar(self,event):
        print("entroooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo")
```

settings.py

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = "ServiHogar2.asgi.application"

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },

}
```

Si necesitan algun dato mas del proyecto, pidanlo y se los doy. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Te falta la parte de `routing`.

Las vistas se tratan de forma distinta si son peticiones HTTP o WS.
Por eso, en el `asgi.py` tienes que configurar la ruta a seguir según el origen. Primero se carga la web vía HTTP, luego vía JS establecerás una conexion typo `WS` con el mismo servidor , y esa se tratará de forma distinta a la anterior:

```
# ServiHogar2/asgi.py
import os

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
import NOMBREDELAAPP.routing

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
  "http": get_asgi_application(),
  "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            NOMBREDELAAPP.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

Ahora nos falta las rutas a nivel de `urls`, lo que es el fichero `url.py` para HTTP, para `WS` siguiendo la documentación oficial, vamos a llamarle  `routing.py`  con contenido:

```
#NOMBREDELAAPP/routing.py
from django.urls import re_path

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/revision/$', consumers.RevisionConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

> Cuidado que en la pregunta has puesto cosumer.py , intuyo que es un error de sintaxis.

> la URL tiene que ser la misma en la función JS que inicializa la conexión WS. Yo le he dicho `ws/revision/`, pon la que quieras.

Asegura que el servidor de desarrollo arranca con ASGI/Channels:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
February 16, 2021 - 00:57:39
Django version 3.1.5, using settings 'testing.settings'
Starting ASGI/Channels version 3.0.3 development server at http://127.0.0.1:8007/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```